# match query vs term query in matching exact field

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Imagine the following schema

```
  {
    "mappings": {
      "my_mappinng": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "_all":       { "enabled": false },
        "_source":    { "enabled": true },
        "properties": {
            "my_string":             { "type": "string",  "store": true, "index" : "not_analyzed" },
            "my_boolean":            { "type": "boolean", "store": true },
            "my_long":               { "type": "long",    "store": true }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
          "number_of_shards" : 9,
          "number_of_replicas" : 1
      }
    }
  }'
```

If I want to have a query that match exact field for `my_string` , `my_boolean` and `my_long`

Is the standard recommendation to

1. set string field to "not_analyzed" in order for it to not get tokenized
2. use term query instead of match query

```
           BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
           QueryBuilder my_filter = QueryBuilders.termQuery("my_string", "string_i_want_to_match");
           query.should(my_filter);

           BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
           QueryBuilder my_filter = QueryBuilders.termQuery("my_boolean", true);
           query.should(my_filter);

           BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
           QueryBuilder my_filter = QueryBuilders.termQuery("my_long", 1l);
           query.should(my_filter);
```

rather than

```
       BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
       query.must(matchQuery("my_string", "string_i_want_to_match"));

       BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
       query.must(matchQuery("my_boolean", true));

       BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
       query.must(matchQuery("my_long", 1l));
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are on old version of ES, where keyword datatype is not supported so in this case you are correct  but if you upgrade ES than instead defining the `not_analyzed`(which is deprecated) you should use the `keyword` data type which as name suggest doesn't change the `text` and creates the token same as input `text` and later `term` query you should use, which is use for exact match scenario.

Please note that in latest version of ES, if you don't define the mapping, by default for every `text` field, one `text` field for full-text searches and one `.keyword` field for aggregation, sorting is created.

In-short, your below Java code is correct for your use-case.

```
  BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
           QueryBuilder my_filter = QueryBuilders.termQuery("my_string", "string_i_want_to_match");
           query.should(my_filter);

           BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
           QueryBuilder my_filter = QueryBuilders.termQuery("my_boolean", true);
           query.should(my_filter);

           BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
           QueryBuilder my_filter = QueryBuilders.termQuery("my_long", 1l);
           query.should(my_filter);
```

Comment: Which exact version are you talking about when you say "latest version of ES"?